# Twitter for iPhone dead after update

Tags: iphone, applications, ipod

I updated Twitter for iPhone on my second generation iPod Touch running iphone OS 3.1.2. After the update, the icon was nowhere to be seen, and I had to restart my iPod to get it back. Attempting to launch the app would get a White screen for a few seconds, and then a crash.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app, and I've had no luck. How can I get the app working again?

Comment: It's dead on the iPhone too. I think it is just Twitter being crap and not testing their app on all platforms before submitting to Apple. Unfortunately, this is quite common in Apple App-land - more than a few talented but still amateur programmers who don't understand the phrase 'legacy support'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Twitter announced](http://twitter.com/mobilesupport/status/20325830954) that the Twitter app is broken on 3.x.x and that a update fixing it is on its way. There's no way you can manually fix it; you just have to wait for the update. Usually a crashing issue is due to low RAM (which is fixed with a restart / reinstall) but this one is a firmware issue.

Comment: Update is available now.